# What does “meth“ mean in “Meth heads snuck in to it to do meth.”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

There was the following passage in the New Yorker’s (September 22, 2014) article titled “Field trip” describing a photographer who travels to take pictures of oldest living things in the world:

> The one she photographed was a 3500 year-old tree just outside
>   Orlando, Florida – actually the original tourist attraction before
>   Disney. **Meth heads snuck into it to do meth**, and they accidentally
>   burned it down. One of them later said, ‘Oh shit, we killed something
>   that was older than Jesus.’

As I had no idea about ‘meth,’ I checked Readers English Japanese Dictionary at hand, which defines it as a slang to mean methyl alcohol or drug, methadone.

Urban Dictionary defines meth as an abbreviation for methamphetamine, a drug that stimulates the central nervous system by causing it to release more dopamine, a neurotransmitter that gives someone a feeling of satisfaction.

Does ‘meth’ in the above quote means methadone or methamphetamine, and 'do meth' mean to take or inhale it? Is it a popular slang as pot and weed are for marijuana?

Comment: [Methamphetamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methamphetamine). I can't believe you couldn't [find it](http://www.drugfreeworld.org/drugfacts/crystalmeth.html).

Comment: @Canis Lupus. I didn't look for Mathamphetamine. I just checked the word 'meth.' Japan is very strict on drug use. Pot is of course illegal. Users go to jail. I'm sure 99.999% of Japanese know neither Metham-whachamacallet nor meth except physicians and chemists.

Comment: America has half a million people in jail for non-alcoholic drug convictions: [how many does Japan have](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2014/05/20/world/social-issues-world/asia-meth-demand-soars-japan-top-market/)?

Comment: @tchrist - Very interesting article; good find. I would guess 99.999% of Americans don't know what “kakuseizai” is.

Comment: ＠tchrist..Based on the latest report of Japan’s Ministry of Health and Welfare, “The status quo and future prospect of drug abuse in Japan,” the combined number of criminals arrested by Police Agency, Marine Police Agency and Narcotic Control Office are total 14.200 in 2013 and 14,965 in 2012. The breakdown (2013) by drug category are Stimulants(Kakuseizai) 12,083, Pot 1,759, Drug 346, and Opium 12. The incidence of drug usage and crimes are much lower than those of U.S. It’s one of the reasons we don’t know the word, meth.

Comment: @medica I'm going to guess *kakuseizai * is a either a very good detective or a weasel. Did my googlefoo fail me? Or is it a stimulant derived from meth or other amphetamines?

Comment: Yes, that’s probably part of it. Another part may be that it appears to be known as *kakuseizai* there; I found quite a few web articles about this growing (and deeply saddening) issue in your country. I was also quite surprised at the relative proportions of the types of illegal drugs arrested for in Japan, as your proportions by type are very different from those seen in America. I have no earthly idea why this might be. I recognize that is beyond the scope of your question, however.

Comment: @Mdedica. That's true. That's why cultural difference really matters in handling questions and answers. As a matter of course to anglophones isn't as a matter of course to us, non-native English speakers, and vice versa to you.

Comment: @CanisLupus Google produces very different results for the same queries when run by different users. When I googled *kakuseizai*, the top five were clearly about illegal stimulant narcotics in Japan.

Comment: @CanisLupus it also depends on your preference settings; how many language you checked/ticked off, search history, and I'm sure there other factors involved too. I would also hope that Yoichi Oishi is using either the USA or UK Google search engine (Canadian, Australian, N.Zealand...). And lets not forget the hugely popular and much-awarded TV series "[Breaking Bad](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/)" was based on a mild mannered Chemistry teacher who creates the purest form of meth ever. Great story, I'd really recommend watching it, also on a language level, very enlightening.

Comment: +1 for the last line quoted in the article "Oh shit, we killed something that was older than Jesus." My first laugh of the day, thank you :D

Comment: Since it hasn't been stated yet, it should be noted that using _meth_ as an abbreviation of _methadone_ is (in my experience, at least) quite rare, precisely because it normally means methamphetamine. _Methadone_ is usually just _methadone_.

Comment: You'd have been able to understand the sentence more easily had you treated [meth head] as a single lexical unit. It's much like the slang word [dopehead](http://www.onelook.com/?w=dopehead&ls=a), only specifically tied to meth, as opposed to drugs in general. One might even say _dopehead_ is a hypernym of _meth head_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the rarity of *meth* as an abbreviation for *methadone* is a sign of the times. A couple of decades ago it would have been much more likely to mean methadone due to changes in patterns of drug use over time, and more so in the UK & Ireland than the US, due to differences in drug use geographically. Go back to the 1950s and it would have meant methanol turned to by alcoholics out of desperation (which still leads to questions when trying to buy it, even when you can get supermarket whiskey for less).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Meth** (or sometimes crystal meth) means **methamphetamine**.  It is the most common name for the drug, at least in the US.  A **meth head** is someone who uses meth.  Most people who understand pot or weed would understand meth.  In exactly the same way that a person would "do heroin" or "do coke" one could "do meth."

Comment: But meth isn't a verb in that phrase either, it's the object of "to do."  You could "do coke" or "do heroin" or "do dishes" even.

Comment: Why is the last sentence in this answer @Jason Patterson? As you say in your comment, it wasn't used in the question this way. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @Henry74 The original question asked for the meaning of "meth" and then went on to ask if could be used as a verb.  The part asking if "to do meth" meant to smoke or inhale was added later.

Comment: If the question was changed significantly, as was the case here, is it better to revert the question to its original form?  The OP asked whether "meth" was a verb, not how to describe using the drug.

Comment: The OP can edit his question whenever he/she sees fit as long as it doesn't radically change the nature of the question, in fact he improved the post. I don't understand your hesitancy to edit your post, if you prefer to leave it as it is, fine. But that last line of yours will always seem a bit odd. (I have deleted my previous comments as they are no longer pertinent)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A There's no real hesitance on my part to edit this answer.  However, in order to find out whether it was the OP or someone else who changed the question, I would first have to discover that the question had been changed, then examine the revision history to ensure that the change had been done by the OP (I actually thought it was someone else,) then change my answer.  If you see that the answer needs changing to fit the question, why not edit it?  This is really a meta question, I suppose...

Comment: The edit history is visible to anyone. Just click on *edited yesterday* button. I'm not castigating you, it was a suggestion to strengthen *your* answer. Take it or leave it. :)

Comment: @Jason patterson.@Mari-Lou A. Regarding the edite of this question. I changed the headline and omitted verb reference after reading Jason’s answer, which I 'approved' earlier.. Rereading the line, it’s obviously “do ＋ noun ” like ‘do golf.’ I’m very sorry to Jason for spoiling your neat answer. All happened because of my total ignorance of the word, meth, which seems to be commonsense in many parts of the world.

Comment: @Jason Patterson, I don't know the rules very well myself, but I think the edit was a good choice. Even though it is good information, a future user looking at this for reference would probably be confused. I've upvoted your answer